# How to find component by their ID?

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

For Example, I have a `Parent` component with following template:

```
<Parent>
  <Child id="foo" @click="doSomething"></Child>
  <Child id="bar" @click="doSomethingElse"></Child>
</Parent>
```

I need to find a `Child` component with specific ID (say the one with id `foo`), so that I can let it trigger an `click` event to the parent. At first, I tried:

```
describe('Parent component', () => {
  it('will do something when Child component with id "foo" triggers "click" event.', () => {
    var wrapper = shallowMount(Parent, {
      /* some other options that doesn't matter here. */
    );
    wrapper.find('#foo').vm.$emit('click');
  });
});
```

It goes wrong because the wrapper return by the `find` method doesn't have `vm` method when you find by a selector, and I don't know how to do next.

Any useful help will be appreciate.

P.S I don't wan't to add extra `ref` the those components, because this add extra code in the implementation code.

Comment: whats wrong with using `ref="foo"`? it is test code anyway

Comment: It doesn’t have any use in the implementation codes.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Child from '../src/componentsChild.vue'

const children =wrapper.findAll(Child).vm.$emit('click');
const fooChild = children.wrappers.find(wrapper => wrapper.vm.$el.id === 'foo')
foo.vm.$emit('click')
```

You *probably* could also use the reference to the component instance that's saved as `__vue__` on the root element, but that would be hacky:

```
wrapper.find('#foo').element.__vue__.$emit('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select child using `const child = document.querySelector('PARENT > #foo');`